# How can a JSON model be handled in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a JSON model in my view which I am passing to a PHP script. The model looks like this:

```
{
        FirstName: "Paul",
        SurName: "Krampe"
}
```

I send it to the backend using JSON.stringify(). In PHP, this object arrives as:

```
{\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Paul\\\",\\\"SurName\\\":\\\"Krampe\\\"}
```

How can I read the members now and assign them to variables?

I tried

```
$firstName = $newUserObject["FirstName"];
```

and

```
$firstName = $newUserObject->FirstName;
```

but they are both null.

Comment: looks like PHP has a module for that: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: Your string isn't JSON anymore in PHP. It's probably been mangled by magic quotes or some other auto-quoting system. You'll have to undo that quoting before you can run it through [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in `json_decode` function

```
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Then access the data with

```
$array['FirstName'];
```

Additionnaly you would have to remove the extra `slashes` in your JSON input by calling before the `json_decode` function the following format function:

```
$json = str_replace('\\\\\\', '', $json);
```

Comment: Cheers, mate! I recognized when playing around with your snippets that $json was already passed as an array. Then, it was simple.

Answer (score 2):

php's function `json_decode()` decodes string JSON argument into an object and returns that object .

---

there's also `json_encode()` function that does the opposite: encodes php object, or array, etc. into JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "yourfile.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
foreach ( $json_output->trends as $trend )
{
echo $trend->name;
}
```